# Merging csv files of inconsistent row length and keeping basename as column header

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a directory full of csv files, that all have a common column (`Class`) and then an integer value, although they have an inconsistent file length. An example `[1:5, ]`:

```
                              Class Abundance_inds
1                       Chaetognath              2
2      Copepod_Calanoid_Acartia_spp              9
3  Copepod_Calanoid_Centropages_spp              4
4       Copepod_Calanoid_Temora_spp              1
5          Copepod_Calanoid_Unknown              5
```

They are exporting for another R script, so the first column needs cropping off before merging, I can merge them successfully using:

```
test <- read.csv(file = csvs[1])[ ,2:3]

test2 <- read.csv(file = csvs[2])[ ,2:3]
```

and then:

```
library(tidyverse)
mergedcsvs <- list(test, test2) %>% reduce(full_join, by = "Class")
```

which gives the following and desired outcome no matter how many files `[1:4,]`:

```
                              Class Abundance_inds.x Abundance_inds.y
1                       Chaetognath                2                4
2      Copepod_Calanoid_Acartia_spp                9               11
3  Copepod_Calanoid_Centropages_spp                4                8
4       Copepod_Calanoid_Temora_spp                1               NA
```

I also want to use the `basename` of the file as the column header, I know I can extract is using this:

```
basename1 <- csvs[1]
basename2 <- csvs[2]
```

I know I can create a list of `basenames` then use these are column headers, but it seems quite impractical to create a dataframe for every single csv (there are lots) then manually do this.

As the CSVs are exported from another R script, they have an additional unneeded first column which needs to be removed.

Surely there is a better way! Any help would be great.

(I have had a mess around with [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-multiple-data-files-into-one-data-frame/) but I can't get it working for me)

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your comment. I am not too stressed on getting the csvs into one list without the first column, the tricky part for me is merging them and keeping the basename, many thanks for your contribution!

Comment: You want the `basename` as the column name for the second column, right?

Comment: Hi! Yep, the first column would be `class`, the second would be the name of the csvs that data is derived from, e.g. `csv1`, then `cs2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more answer using fast `fread` from `library(data.table)`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(tools)

write.csv(data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                     Class = c("Chaetognath", "Copepod_Calanoid_Acartia_spp",
                               "Copepod_Calanoid_Centropages_spp",
                               "Copepod_Calanoid_Temora_spp"),
                     Abundance_inds = c(2, 9, 4, 1)
), file = "x.csv")

write.csv(data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                     Class = c("Chaetognath", "Copepod_Calanoid_Acartia_spp",
                               "Copepod_Calanoid_Centropages_spp"),
                     Whatever = c(4, 11, 8)
), file = "y.csv")

csvPaths <- list.files(".", "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

csvList <- list()
for(csvPath in csvPaths){
  csvList[[csvPath]] <- fread(csvPath, col.names = c("Class", basename(file_path_sans_ext(csvPath))), drop = 1)
}

mergedcsvs <- csvList %>% reduce(full_join, by = "Class")

#                              Class x.csv y.csv
# 1                      Chaetognath     2     4
# 2     Copepod_Calanoid_Acartia_spp     9    11
# 3 Copepod_Calanoid_Centropages_spp     4     8
# 4      Copepod_Calanoid_Temora_spp     1    NA
```

---

Edit: Here is a `data.table` only way (avoiding `library(tidyverse)`)

```
csvPaths <- list.files(".", "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

csvList <- list()
for(csvPath in csvPaths){
  csvList[[csvPath]] <- fread(csvPath, drop = 1, col.names = c("class", "vars"))[, id := basename(file_path_sans_ext(csvPath))]
}

DT <- rbindlist(csvList, use.names = FALSE)
mergedDT <- dcast.data.table(DT, class ~ id, value.var = "vars")
mergedDT
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer. Although Its not working for me but I am sure its because I have an additional first column with numbers assigned during a `write.csv` from a different script, any ideas to remove that first column within your function. (same comment as above)

Answer (score 3):

Using the test input shown in the Note at the end read in the files given in the `filenames` character vector and then `merge` them.  Finally set the names.  The tools package comes with R so you don't need to install it.

```
library(tools)

LL <- Map(read.csv, filenames, as.is = TRUE)
r <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "Class"), LL)
names(r)[-1] <- basename(file_path_sans_ext(filenames))
```

giving:

```
                             Class DF1 DF2 DF3
1                      Chaetognath   2  NA   2
2     Copepod_Calanoid_Acartia_spp   9   9   9
3 Copepod_Calanoid_Centropages_spp   4   4  NA
4      Copepod_Calanoid_Temora_spp   1   1   1
5         Copepod_Calanoid_Unknown  NA   5   5
```

Depending on what you want for output you may need `all = FALSE` in place of the `all` argument shown.

### Note

I have provided test data for you below this time but this really should have been provided in the problem along with exactly what output you expect.

```
Lines <- "                              Class Abundance_inds
1                       Chaetognath              2
2      Copepod_Calanoid_Acartia_spp              9
3  Copepod_Calanoid_Centropages_spp              4
4       Copepod_Calanoid_Temora_spp              1
5          Copepod_Calanoid_Unknown              5"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
L <- list(DF1 = DF[1:4, ], DF2 = DF[2:5, ], DF3 = DF[-3, ])
filenames <- paste0(names(L), ".csv")
for(i in seq_along(filenames)) write.csv(L[[i]], filenames[i], row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer. Although Its not working for me but I am sure its because I have an additional first column with numbers assigned during a `write.csv` from a different script, any ideas to remove that first column within your function.

Comment: Try this  `LL <- Map(function(x) read.csv(x, as.is = TRUE)[-1], filenames)
`

Comment: It chucks up 26 warnings on the second line, but I am confused to how to generate the table from the three lines given. Thanks for you continued help!

Comment: It does not give any errors or warnings when using the data shown in the Note at end.  The problem is that there is no reproducible data in the question and it is up to you to provide that.

Comment: Yes thanks, I am well aware of that and tried to construct some but that is a lesson itself, I will have a go at it now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

one possibility would be to read the data.frames into a nested tibble.
Therefore you first define a function which describes how to read and transform a single dataframe. In your case this is how it could look like:

```
library(tidyverse)

read_onecsv <- function(csvname, columnname) {
  read.csv(file = csvname) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
    select(2:3) %>% mutate(type = columnname)
}
```

This function reads one csv file, transforms it to a tibble, selects columns 2 and 3 and then create a dummy column (named `type`) which contains the later column names.

Next you create a tibble with all `csvnames` and all `columnnames` and run the following:

```
tibble(csvnames = c("csv1.csv", "csv2.csv"), columnnames = c("col1", "col2")) %>%
    mutate(data = map2(csvnames, columnnames, read_onecsv))%>%
    unnest() %>%
    spread(type, Abundance_inds)
```

Comment: Hi, Cheers for you answer, I am looking for a solution whereby it can be run on purely the file names. Many thanks, that was my initial approach too

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution with `list.files` and `lapply`.

```
library(readr)

## read all names with .csv at the end form your working directory and save as variable
fileNames <- list.files(pattern = '.csv')

## read all files, merge and save as tibble
fileList <- lapply(1:length(fileNames), function(i) read_csv(fileNames[i]) %>%
 select(-1)
) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = 'class')

## rename columns
names(fileList) <- c(names(fileList)[1], sub('.csv', "", fileNames))

## output
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  class  test1 test10
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 banana     1      1
2 apples     1      1
3 orange    10     NA
4 ginger    NA      5
```

---

I have created two .csv files (test1.csv & test10.csv) for testing purposes

**File test1.csv**

```
number, class,value
1,banana,1
2,apples,1
3,orange,10
```

**File test10.csv**

```
number, class,value
1,banana,1
2,apples,1
3,ginger,5
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, it chucks up the following error: `> fileList <- lapply(1:length(fileNames) function(i) read_csv(fileNames[i])) %>% 
Error: unexpected 'function' in "fileList <- lapply(1:length(fileNames) function"
>   reduce(full_join, by = 'class')
Error in x[[1]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` could this be to do with the extra column that exists within the csvs, column 1 needs clipping?

Comment: my fault, forget the `,` in `fileList <- lapply(1:length(fileNames), function(i) read_csv(fileNames[i]))`

Comment: with within `reduce(full_join, by = 'class')`, would you mind updating your answer! sorry to ask

Comment: Updated and tested

Comment: Its not working for me but I am sure its because I have an additional first column with numbers assigned during a `write.csv` from a different script, any ideas to remove that first column?

Comment: If you it's everytime the first column you could use `%>% select(-1)` in the `lapply` statement. Answer updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193145/discussion-between-jim-and-patrick).